# What info do we get from the "raw gradient"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have the function $f(x,y)=2x^2-y^2$.

The gradient is
$$
grad(f)=    \begin{bmatrix}
    4x \\
    -2y \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I know that if I input a point that I get the direction in which $f$ changes most rapidly. But is there anything that the "raw gradient" can give me?

Comment: From the gradient, you can find where the function may have a maximum or a minimum. You can also find the equations of tangent lines and tangent planes.

Comment: True but anything about the gradient without an operation? So only [4x, -2y]?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, I think. What kind of information do you want? This is virtualy the same as asking what information does the derivative encode. After all, the gradient is just the derivative of a function of many variables.